# how can I find the character table of $(Z/9Z)^\times$?

Tags: representation-theory, characters, sagemath

I tried using sagemath. But I don't think sagemath is supporting character table of multiplicative groups of $(Z/nZ)^\times$. Also it would be great if you can suggest a way to calculate character table of $(Z/9Z)^\times$ which I can generalise into character table of $(Z/p^2Z)^\times$, where p is prime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All the $(\Bbb Z/p^2\Bbb Z)^\times$ are cyclic groups.

Comment: All I need to find out is whether  $(Z/p^2Z)^\times$  have an irreducible representation with  character  values {1,-1}. It  is true when p=2. But I am not able to figure out when p>2.

Comment: Yes: the group is cyclic of even order: you can use the Legendre symbol.

Comment: I read about Legendre symbol just now but  didn’t get the relationship between this and characters. Could you please elaborate ,or give me some references?

Comment: The group's abelian, so all its irreps are $1$-dimensional, i.e., maps to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Apparently there *is* a way to get this programmatically in Sage, see https://ask.sagemath.org/question/29639/easiest-way-to-work-in-the-multiplicative-group-of-zmodn/

Answer (score 2):

I'll break this into steps using spoilers so you can try for yourself.

First, calculate what $G=(Z/9Z)^\times$ is.

> To do this use the fact that the multiplicative subgroup has order $\phi(9)=6$ where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), by doing some basic calculations we find the group has the elements $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$ and is isomorphic to a cyclic group of order 6.

Now we know what the group is we can apply basic character theory:

> We know the group is abelian, so it must have $|G|=6$ conjugacy classes, and thus 6 irreducible representations, as our group is Abelian every representation is linear and thus a character.
>  We immediately know one of these is the trivial representation and by the representation theory of abelian groups, the other representations are $1$-dimensional and the values take sixth roots of unity.

We can obtain these through lifting from the normal subgroups

> For example, we can lift two nontrivial characters from the quotient group of  $G/\{1,8\}$ and a non-trivial character from the quotient $G/\{1,4,7\}$.

The full table:

> $\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
> &1&8&4&7&2&5\\
> \hline
> ρ_1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
> ρ_2&1&-1&1&1&-1&-1\\
> ρ_3&1&1&\zeta_3&\zeta_3&\zeta_3&\zeta_3^2\\
> ρ_4&1&-1&\zeta_3^2&\zeta_3&\zeta_6^5&\zeta_6\\
> ρ_5&1&1&\zeta_3&\zeta_3^2&\zeta_3^2&\zeta_3\\  
> ρ_6&1&-1&\zeta_3&\zeta_3^2&\zeta_6&\zeta_6^5\\\end{array}$
>
> where $\zeta_k=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{k}}$.

Comment: Oh , got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about doing it in Sagemath, note that a similar answer to this is available at [this question](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/30501/how-do-i-create-the-character-table-of-the-group-of-units-mod-n/).

```
sage: H = Integers(9)
sage: G = H.unit_group()
sage: G
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C6
sage: GG = gap(G)
sage: C = gap.CharacterTable(GG)
sage: gap.Display(C)
CT1

     2  1   1  1  1  1   1
     3  1   1  1  1  1   1

       1a  6a 3a 2a 3b  6b

X.1     1   1  1  1  1   1
X.2     1  -1  1 -1  1  -1
X.3     1   A /A  1  A  /A
X.4     1  -A /A -1  A -/A
X.5     1  /A  A  1 /A   A
X.6     1 -/A  A -1 /A  -A

A = E(3)^2
  = (-1-Sqrt(-3))/2 = -1-b3
```